# Incompatible Types JOptionPane java string to png

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Well, I have a little problem here, I want to add an image to a JOptionPane but I can't because I am converting it as a string! I don't know how to solve it! Help! This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class TextBox {
        
        ImageIcon icon0 = new ImageIcon("Picture2_2.png");
        String user_input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a card number!", "¡Tu puedes!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon0,null,"");
   
    public static void main (String [] args)
        
        {
           
            int g = -1;
            while (g<0)
            {
                
                TextBox n = new TextBox();
                
                if(n.user_input.length() > 0 )
                        {
                            numbersreader t= new numbersreader();
                            t.checkLuhn (n.user_input);
                              g++;
                                                    
                        }else
                            {
                            ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("Picture2_2.png");
                            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a card number!", "¡Ya valio!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon1, null, "");
                            }
            }
        }


}
```

If it wasn't for this the code does work, a version of the code that works is down below but I really want to put that picture in that JOptionPane, there is got to be a way to!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class TextBox {
        
        
        String user_input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a card number!", "¡Tu puedes!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   
    public static void main (String [] args)
        
        {
           
            int g = -1;
            while (g<0)
            {
                
                TextBox n = new TextBox();
                
                if(n.user_input.length() > 0 )
                        {
                            numbersreader t= new numbersreader();
                            t.checkLuhn (n.user_input);
                              g++;
                                                    
                        }else
                            {
                            ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("Picture2_2.png");
                            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a card number!", "¡Ya valio!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon1, null, "");
                            }
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Please give code a consistent & logical form of indentation before posting it here. Most IDEs have a shortcut for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to compile your code the compiler tells me "error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String".

That is because [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Object,int,int,javax.swing.Icon,java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object)) returns some Object, but on line 6 you try to assign the return value to a `String` variable.

After changing line 6 to

```
String user_input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a card number!", "¡Tu puedes!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon0,null,"");
```

(and providing a png file "Picture2_2.png" and a class `numbersreader` with a method `void checkLuhn(String s) {}`) I can compile and run your code.